# gnome-shell Window buttons have disappeared

Tags: gnome-shell

I've just installed the latest version of gnome-shell and it doesn't have window buttons? Is there an entry in gconf-editor that I can change to enable those buttons? In general, how do you tweak gnome-shell?

Comment: What do you mean by windows buttoms?   Minimiza and maximize buttons?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a certain amount of tweaking using gnome-tweak-tool. In Fedora 15 you can use yum to install it.  No sure if it is yet available for other GNU/Linux distributions.

Comment: Thanks, but at the time of writing my question, this tool was not available.